# How do I form a rectangle out of my secret message string

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a secret code app where

```
"If man was meant to stay on the ground, god would have given us roots."
```

is normalized to:

```
"ifmanwasmeanttostayonthegroundgodwouldhavegivenusroots"
```

The normalised text will form a rectangle (​r × c​) where ​c​ is the number of columns and ​r​ is the number of rows such that ​c >= r​ and ​c - r <= 1​,

So for instance the normalized text is 54 characters long, dictating a rectangle with ​c = 8​ and ​r = 7​:

```
"ifmanwas"
"meanttos"
"tayonthe"
"groundgo"
"dwouldha"
"vegivenu"
"sroots "
```

Then the coded message is obtained by reading down the columns going left to right and used to form **encoded chunks** like this

```
"imtgdvs fearwer mayoogo anouuio ntnnlvt wttddes aohghn sseoau"
```

The encoded message/cypher text forms a rectangle like.

```
"imtgdvs"
"fearwer"
"mayoogo"
"anouuio"
"ntnnlvt"
"wttddes"
"aohghn "
"sseoau "
```

I have normalised the plain text ✅

I have not been able to make a rectangle of the normalised text ❌

I have not separated the encoded code in chunks as a single string ❌

I have written the encoded message in a rectangle ✅

```js
const string = document.querySelector('#message');
        const error = document.querySelector('#alert');
         
        const encodeMessage = () => {
            const message = string.value;
            const normalisedText = message.replace(/[^\w]/g, "").toLowerCase();
            const textCount = normalisedText.length;
            const wordCount = message.split(" ").length;
            const cols = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(textCount));
            const rows = Math.ceil(textCount / cols);

            if (wordCount < 2 || message.length < 50) {
            error.innerHTML = `You have ${textCount} character(s) and ${wordCount} word(s). Input must be more than one word and at Least 50 characters!`;
            return false;
            }
  
            let cypherText = "";

            for (let i = 0; i < cols; i ++) { 
                for (let j = i; j < normalisedText.length; j += cols) {
                    cypherText += normalisedText[j];
                }
                cypherText += '\n';
            }

            // document.querySelector('#normalized_rectangle').innerHTML = normalisedText in rectangle;
            // document.querySelector('#encoded_chunks').innerHTML = cypherText as a single text with space in between;
            document.querySelector('#encoded_rectangle').innerHTML = cypherText;
            return cypherText;
        }
```

```html
<form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Type your secret message" id="message">
                <button type="button" class="button" onclick="encodeMessage()">Encode message</button>
            </form>
            <p id="alert"></p>     
      
            <div class="box">
                <h3>Normalised Rectangle</h3>
                <p id="normalized_rectangle"></p>
            </div>
    
            <div class="box">
                <h3>Encoded Chunks</h3>
                <p id="encoded_chunks">
            </p>
            </div>
    
            <div class="box">
                <h3>Encoded Rectangle</h3>
                <p id="encoded_rectangle">
            </p>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the string and use **substring** to make strings of 8 length then push it in an array the loop again on array and make new strings

```js
    text = "ifmanwasmeanttostayonthegroundgodwouldhavegivenusroots";
    c = 8;
    r = 7;
    arr = [];
    cipherText = "";
    plainText = "";
    index = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < r; i++) {
      arr.push(text.substring(index, index + 8))
      index = index + 8;
      plainText = plainText + arr[i]+"\n";
    }
    for (j = 0; j < c; j++) {
      str = ""
      for (k = 0; k < r; k++) {
      if(arr[k][j] != undefined)  str = str + arr[k][j];

      }
      cipherText = cipherText + str +"\t";
    }
    console.log(plainText);
    console.log(cipherText);
```

Comment: I need to treat everything as strings, commas are not allowed to appear as it is when an array of strings

Comment: @Chioma no problem in that you can concat the values in the string inspite of pushing them in an array

Comment: One more thing actually, `cipherText ` is not supposed to be a different string on a new line, it is supposed to a single string with spaces,